# How to replace the value of the variable inside the function by the latest values because of +=(addition assignment) for the next function calling?

Tags: python, pandas

**I want the last value of nomu replace the nomu = 49 for the next and the next funtion calling**

is This my file. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AUdXPyRUtM44hTuvT5UkYqgDw1Do7y43/view?usp=sharing

This is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
os.chdir(r'D:\Documents\Trading\csv')

df = pd.read_csv('02.csv', sep=';')

def filter_Volume(range1, range2):
    filter = (df[df['Sum of Net vol'].between(range1, range2) 
        & ~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('.NG', na=False)
        & ~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('-W', na=False)
        & ~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('Grand Total', na=False)  
        & ~df['Row Labels'].str.contains('.TN', na=False)])
    saham_terfilter = (filter['Row Labels'])

    num = 0
    global nomu
    nomu = 49
    for saham in saham_terfilter:
        num += 1
        if num > 50:
            num = 1
        nomu += 1
        if nomu%50==0:
            nomu1 = int(nomu/50)
            nomu2 = str(nomu1).rjust(3, '0')
            print('interest{}'.format(nomu2))
        print(num, saham)
    return(nomu) 
    
filter_Volume(0, 70000)
filter_Volume(0, 70000)


'''# THIS IS THE RESULT OF CALLING THE FUNCTION
# Ignore why the function contains same arguments
47 XIIT
48 XIJI
49 XMIG
50 XSSI
interest011 #latest chunks of 50 lines from first function
1 YPAS
2 YULE
3 ZBRA
4 ZONE
5 ZYRX
interest001 #first chunks of 50 lines from the second function, i want to make this as 'interest013', therefore i must the last nomu's value is replaced the nomu = 49
1 AALI
2 ABMM
3 ACST
4 ADES
5 ADHI
6 ADMF
7 ADMG
8 AGAR
9 AGII
10 AIMS
11 AISA
12 AKKU
13 AKPI'''
```

Please give any advice or any suggestion that can make interestxxx, go on within the calling of the functions

Comment: Can you please provide some data as well as expected results?

Comment: i provide the data in the link

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by nomu, can you explain it?